# Adding library giving me error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing android library named MyLib. MyLib need a dependency named SubLib. MyLib import SubLib with 'compileOnly/provided'.

`compileOnly 'com.zuga:SubLib:1.0.0'`

Then, App import MyLib with 'api/implementation/compile'.

`implementation 'com.zuga:SubLib:1.0.0'
   implementation project(':MyLib')`

While MyLib want to use SubLib's layout file named key_layout.xml, I got a error.

`Error:(37, 32) error: cannot find symbol variable key_layout`

I don't want to use 'api/implementation/compile' to import SubLib. Please give me some solutions.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `implementation`?

Comment: Because, Other library depend on SubLib too and this library is also used in my app.

Comment: Rather than embarking on a series of questions and answers I suggest you expand your question by showing the different approaches you have tried, and what errors you get for those. That will enable someone to offer you help with the real problem, rather than what you have assumed to be the problem.